# Размер и расположение фотографии, вызываемой через js

Tags: javascript, html

решил создать скрипт, вызывающий рандомное изображение в теге `header`при перезагрузке страницы. Но сама проблема заключается в том, что изображение довольно-таки большое и вылезает за пределы экрана. Я не понимаю, можно ли в js-код внести какие-либо изменения, которые позволили бы изменить размер изображения в зависимости от размера экрана

```
  function getRand(min, max){
  return Math.round(Math.random()*(max-min))+min;
 }

 var images = new Array("img/1.jpg", "img/2.jpg", "img/7.jpg");
 var lo = 0;
 var hi = images.length-1;
 var num = getRand(lo, hi);
 document.write("<img style='border:1px solid #002244; border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;' src='"+images[num]+"'>");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрите, вот строка

```
document.write("<img style='border:1px solid #002244; border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;' src='"+images[num]+"'>");
```

В стили добавьте свойства `width`(ширина) и `height`(высота), получиться как то так.

```
document.write("<img style='width: 100px; height: 100px; border:1px solid #002244; border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;' src='"+images[num]+"'>");
```

Вот и всё.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, а можно ли добавить сюда же свойство автоизменения размера изображения при изменении размера окна браузера? Я так понимаю, что для этого нужно только фиксированное значение height, а что насчёт width- не знаю(
И второе, можно ли добавить ссылки в эти изображения, которые, допустим, будут вести юзера на главную сайта?

Comment: @Эдуард Навальный `document.write("<img style='width: 70%; height: auto; border:1px solid #002244; border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;' src='"+images[num]+"'>");` - вот так попробуйте. А вообще используйте framework bootstrap там есть всё и классы responsive для изображений.